Changing response of Moq ReturnsAsync
I'm trying to mock a singleton which will reuse an HttpClient in each test, due to the static nature of it's internal values.
In each xUnit test, I am attempting to reset the response value, like this:
_mockHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(response);

So, in the first test the response would be something like:
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent(jsonContent)
};

And in the second test it would be something like:
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent("[]")
};

The issue is that when the second test calls .ReturnsAsync(response) with its content, this does not appear to change the response value of the HttpClient.
Am I misunderstanding the logic of the Moq library, doing it wrong or is there genuinely something amiss?

It's not clear to me what the problem is. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.
